# Oracle low cardinality column index ordering performance

Tags: oracle, performance, database-design

I have a table with `control_type` column that stores NUMBER and can have only three values, as 1, 2 and 3

Assuming that table contains about 50 000 000 data, I want to query that table according to `control_type` value. Does index definition ordering on `control_type` column effect performance (ASC or DESC)?

Answer (score 2):

You will *never* want to use an index to query a table with 50M rows on a column with three values. You will need say 17M *index access* to get all rows with one value (assuming non skewed distribution) which will take *ages*.

You need to perform a *full table scan* possible with *parallel option*.

The only exception is if your column contains skew data, say the `1` is in nearly all rows and `2`and `3` are very exceptional (few thousand or so) - that use the index for the low occurece values.

A *frequecy historgram* will help the optimizer to make this decision.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an even distribution of values, your suggested index will have 17 million hits per value. That is not a sensible case for building an index.  Indexed reads are too expensive for such a large amount of data. And that's before we consider whether the values are clustered or spread throughout the table. Even if the values of `control_type` are heavily skewed, a query on the minority value(s) using indexed reads might still visit every block in the table, if the values are distributed across the whole table.

In almost every scenario it's likely the most efficient means of finding records for a given value of `control_type` is a Full Table Scan and a filter. If you have multiple available CPUs use parallel query, and solve it with crunch.

Although, if you have a query which is going to return 17 million rows you might what to revisit the requirements: who or what is interested in that data?

Also, consider whether you can partition the table? 50 million rows sounds like a table which might benefit from that (provided your organisation has sprung for the Partitioning Option license). I'm not suggesting you partition on  `control_type`, but there maybe some other suitable column, such as a transaction date?